# Encountering SCRIPT 1003 error on IE11 with webpack and VueJS

Tags: webpack, vue.js, internet-explorer-11

I have an application written in VueJS which uses Webpack to create the bundle.js file to deploy on the browser. This works fine on Chrome but when I run the app on IE 11, I get the following error...

```
SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'
bundle.js (23469,9)
```

The line 23469 in bundle.js looks like this...

```
const app = new __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_vue__["a" /* default */]({
  router,
  render: h => h(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__App_vue___default.a)
}).$mount('#app');
```

Line 23469 is specifically pointing to the 'router,'

I cannot quite figure out what the issue is. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you change `router,` to `router: router,` in the `new Vue` constructor object?

Comment: I agree with @thanksd. I think IE11 cant run ES6 code. Have you got compiling to ES5 in webpack?

Comment: The arrow function is a problem aswell, this is not supported by EI 11, chances are you are not using babel or if the function is a class member it is not transpiled in that case i suggest using a normal function. Or add babel-transform-class-properties plugin to your webpack to convert them

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your webpack configuration does not include polyfills for browsers like IE11 that don't support ES6. The solution is to configure your webpack to use babel-polyfill ([source](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/)):

The instructions are as follows:

1. Run `npm install --save babel-polyfill` in your project root directory (note that it says --save and not --save-dev, since the polyfills are required at runtime too)
2. Include babel-polyfill in your webpack config file: `require("babel-polyfill");`, or if you're using ES6: `import 'babel-polyfill'`
3. Modify your entry point to include babel-polyfill:

   ```
   module.exports = {
     entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./app/js"]
   };
   ```